# Gradle - Building Java Web Applications

Tags: gradle

I try to do this tutorial since several days.
I have installed Jetty and launch with java -jar start.jar.

But there is a problem and I can't run on http://localhost:8080/webdemo.

On Gradle https://guides.gradle.org/building-java-web-applications/?_ga=2.70016208.115474122.1530432194-1213495054.1529791313

When we do this command bash gradlew appRun, that's the result:

```
$ ./gradlew appRun
:prepareInplaceWebAppFolder
:createInplaceWebAppFolder UP-TO-DATE
:compileJava
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes
:prepareInplaceWebAppClasses
:prepareInplaceWebApp
:appRun
12:25:13 INFO  Jetty 9.2.15.v20160210 started and listening on port 8080
12:25:13 INFO  webdemo runs at:
12:25:13 INFO    http://localhost:8080/webdemo
Press any key to stop the server.
> Building 87% > :appRun
```

But this is my result:

```
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 busy Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass (file:/home/koala/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy/2.4.11/52a60df8b4cbfe39469171a42ca77a3e4eb4e737/groovy-2.4.11.jar) to method java.lang.Object.finalize()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getText() on null object
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject.invokeMethod(NullObject.java:91)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.NullCallSite.call(NullCallSite.java:35)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
        at org.akhikhl.gretty.Runner.initLogback(Runner.groovy:65)
        at org.akhikhl.gretty.Runner$initLogback.callStatic(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallStatic(CallSiteArray.java:56)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:194)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:206)
        at org.akhikhl.gretty.Runner.run(Runner.groovy:115)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:210)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:71)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117)
        at org.akhikhl.gretty.Runner.main(Runner.groovy:44)
Exception in thread "Thread-23" org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-10-oracle/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
        at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:395)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultJavaExecAction.execute(DefaultJavaExecAction.java:37)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFileOperations.javaexec(DefaultFileOperations.java:192)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.javaexec(DefaultProject.java:1087)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.javaexec(DefaultProject.java:1082)
        at org.gradle.api.Project$javaexec$6.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
        at org.akhikhl.gretty.DefaultLauncher.javaExec(DefaultLauncher.groovy:89)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:384)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:69)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:166)
        at org.akhikhl.gretty.LauncherBase$_launchThread_closure4.doCall(LauncherBase.groovy:256)
        at org.akhikhl.gretty.LauncherBase$_launchThread_closure4.doCall(LauncherBase.groovy)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:414)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:408)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.run(Closure.java:495)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
<===========--> 87% EXECUTING [10m 47s]
> :appRun
> IDLE
```

Many thanks for unblock my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The guide is out of date, sorry. Replace the block:

```
plugins {
    id 'war'
    id 'org.akhikhl.gretty' version '1.4.2' 
}
```

with

```
plugins {
    id 'war'
    id 'org.gretty' version '2.2.0' 
}
```

I'll schedule the guide for an update.

The warning is not critical and is the result of changes to the JVM between major versions. You can learn more about it in [the Gradle issue tracker](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/2995).

Comment: There are two bases of Gretty. One is [org.gretty](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.gretty) and has at time of writing v 2.3.1. Then there is the [org.akhikhl.gretty](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.akhikhl.gretty) currently at v 2.0.0. Use the org.gretty one.